# karma jasmine tests do not run on Firefox 32.0.x

Tags: angularjs, firefox, karma-runner, permission-denied

my karma jasmine unit tests do not run with Firefox verion 32.0.x.
here is my karma.conf

```
module.exports = function (config) {
config.set({

    preprocessors: {
        // make html files accessable within a karma test
        'app/views/**/*.html': ['ng-html2js'],
        // source files, that you wanna generate coverage for
        // do not include tests or libraries
        // (these files will be instrumented by Istanbul)
        'app/scripts/**/*.js': ['coverage']
    },

    // base path, that will be used to resolve files and exclude
    basePath: '',

    // testing framework to use (jasmine/mocha/qunit/...)
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],

    // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
    files: [
        'app/bower_components/angular/angular.js',
        'app/bower_components/json3/lib/json3.js',
        'app/bower_components/es5-shim/es5-shim.js',
        'app/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js',
        'app/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
        'app/bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js',
        'app/bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js',
        'app/bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js',
        'app/bower_components/angular-translate/angular-translate.js',
        'app/bower_components/bison-corporatedesign/directives/headerbar.js',
        'app/bower_components/angular-grid/ng-grid-2.0.13.debug.js',
        'app/bower_components/angular-ui-utils/ui-utils.js',
        'app/bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js',
        'app/bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js',
        'app/bower_components/AngularJS-Toaster/toaster.js',
        'app/bower_components/angular-google-chart/ng-google-chart.js',
        'app/bower_components/socket.io-client/dist/socket.io.min.js',
        'app/bower_components/angular-dynamic-locale/src/tmhDynamicLocale.js',
        'app/bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js',
        'app/scripts/directives/*.js',
        'app/scripts/*.js',
        'app/scripts/**/*.js',
        'test/spec/**/*.js',

        'app/views/**/*.html'
    ],

    reporters: ['progress', 'junit', 'coverage'],

    // list of files / patterns to exclude
    exclude: ['./**/*.js.map'],

    // web server port
    port: 9001,

    // level of logging
    // possible values: LOG_DISABLE || LOG_ERROR || LOG_WARN || LOG_INFO || LOG_DEBUG
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,

    // enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
    autoWatch: true,

    // Start these browsers, currently available:
    // - Chrome
    // - ChromeCanary
    // - Firefox
    // - Opera
    // - Safari (only Mac)
    // - PhantomJS
    // - IE (only Windows)
    browsers: ['PhantomJS', 'Firefox'],

    junitReporter: {
        outputFile: 'distribution/junit/TESTS-results.xml'
    },

    coverageReporter: {
        type: 'cobertura',
        dir: 'distribution/cobertura/'
    },

    // Continuous Integration mode
    // if true, it capture browsers, run tests and exit
    singleRun: false
});};
```

i use the karma-firefox-launcher.
When i run grunt karma firefox will be startet up but the test failed because there is no communication.

error-log on Firefox console:

```
Error: Permission denied to access object
Error: Permission denied to access property 'result'
```

any idea how to solve this? older versions worked well.

Comment: Are you using unsafeWindow anywhere in your code?  See documentation here:  https://blog.mozilla.org/addons/2014/04/10/changes-to-unsafewindow-for-the-add-on-sdk/

Comment: no. dont know if this is used somewhere in the karma oder jasmine logic but generally is use alot uf expect().toBe statements.
tests passed on chrome and ie 11.